# Android Pjsip: Audio Conference Call

Tags: java, android, pjsip, pjsua2

I am implementing Audio Conference Call in **Android** using **Pjsip library** v2.6. What I have done is:

Call **A -> B**

Put **B** on **hold**

Call **A -> C**

Re-invite **B**

The issue I am facing is, I can hear voice from **A -> B** and **A -> C**. But there is **no voice transmission** between **B -> C**.

I think something is missing related to **connection bridge** between B -> C but I am not getting any hint for that.

Can any one advice me how to create that or how to proceed?

Thank you in advance...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented using [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/pjsip-doc/media) steps and it worked.

All I did is:

Get **AudioMedia** of B and C and **started transmission** between them like above mentioned link.

Comment: Can you please post snippet to connect audioMedias of different calls all together? pls..